# ReactJS ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to set up a basic ReactJS project without much success, I have these three files:

[index.html]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>MarkEdit</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/minireset.css"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/index.css"></link>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/babel" src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/babel" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main id="application"></main>
    </body>
</html>
```

[scripts/app.js]

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

[scripts/index.js]

```
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("application"));
```

And I've been getting these errors:

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

All the files are available and served through a Golang webserver. I do not have a JS bundler like Webpack and I was wondering what I'm currently doing wrong. I have tried `import` but I just get:

```
ReferenceError: import is not defined
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This question is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59483131/cant-write-html-in-react-components/59486867#59486867

Comment: @MattCarlotta but I do use babel whereas the author of the question you just linked does not.

Comment: He does, he just didn't include it in his example (see his first example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59461002/how-to-link-reference-multiple-scripts-in-an-html-file-with-react-without-node/59466292#59466292). Again, `JSX` isn't valid `HTML`. As of now, you'll be making the client transpile it for EVERY visit. Instead, it should be compiled to JS. However, when compiled, it still needs a third party library to handle `require` (`import` compiles to `require`) statements.

Comment: Recommend to startup a React app through Create-React-APP. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: It seems that babel isn't transpiling the code, how are you applying the babel transpilation? Are you using webpack (if so, what's your config)?

Comment: @zxxxj I do not want to use NodeJS as a back-end, I want to use Golang, which is the reason why I'm not using the create-react-app module

Comment: @Jayce444 I'm not using webpack or any other bundler...

Comment: @Whiteclaws create-react-app doesn't require you to use nodejs as a back-end. It uses npm to facilitate the creation of the front-end files. Your back-end can be whatever you want it to be so long as you communicate with it via XHR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot your imports and these are important to use its features, otherwise it will reference error: "imports are not defined"

Try adding this

```
import React from "react";
```

before

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

and inside your index.js file just add this

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("application");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you following the same?

[scripts/App.js]

```
import React from "react";
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, World!</h1>;
  }
}
```

[scripts/index.js]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("application");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```